# React Router Link is Showing Two Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I didn't know the best way to describe this issue, but I'm going to try and explain as best I can.

In my core React App component, i'm doing a conditional render, based on if a user is logged in.

If Logged In --- I show the main page, and if not, they get the login screen.

On my login page, i'm trying to put in a link at the bottom which directs a user to signup for a new account.  My issue that when I click to this 'newuser' page, it is rendering both my login form and the create user form, both different components (see below).

I suspect this is an issue with how I have my react router setup, but I'm not sure what the problem is.

[image]

Here is the code in my App component.

```
 <Container>
      <Router>
        <Notification />
        {props.loggedUser ? (
          <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Blogs />} />
            <Route exact path="/blogs" render={() => <Blogs />} />
            <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login />} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/blogs/:id"
              render={({ match }) => (
                <Blog
                  blog={blogById(match.params.id)}
                  user={props.loggedUser}
                />
              )}
            />
            <Route exact path="/users" render={() => <Users />} />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/users/:id"
              render={({ match }) => <User user={userById(match.params.id)} />}
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Login />
          </>
        )}
      </Router>
      <div>
        <br />
        <em>Blog app, John 2019</em>
      </div>
    </Container>
```

And here is my Login component.  I've tried including the route for the new users page on both sides of the conditional statement above and then also in the Login Form below, as I have now.  All are leading to the same issue.

```
<h1>Login To Blog Application</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>username</label>
          <input {...username.omitreset} name="username" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>password</label>
          <input {...password.omitreset} type="password" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit">login</Button>
        <div>
          <br />
          <Link to="/newuser">or signup to become a new user</Link>
          <Route path="/newuser" render={() => <NewUser />} />
        </div>
      </Form>
    </>
```

and NewUser component

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { createUser } from "../reducers/userReducer";
import { setNotification } from "../reducers/notificationReducer";
import { Form, Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

const NewUser = props => {
  const addUser = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const userObject = {
      username: event.target.username.value,
      name: event.target.name.value,
      password: event.target.password.value
    };

    event.target.username.value = "";
    event.target.name.value = "";
    event.target.password.value = "";
    props.createUser(userObject);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Create a New Blog Account</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={addUser}>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>username</label>
          <input {...props.username} name="username" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>name</label>
          <input {...props.name} type="password" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Field>
          <label>password</label>
          <input {...props.password} type="password" />
        </Form.Field>
        <Button type="submit">login</Button>
      </Form>
    </>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  createUser,
  setNotification
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(NewUser);
```

Comment: There aren't sufficient details to answer this question. you haven't told us which route is the "New Users" page, so debugging by reading your code is impossible. also, why are you including the login in your routes if user is already logged in? that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've included the NewUser component which is the component rendered for the link below the Login form.  Hopefully this helps.  I can see what you mean by the login route--i'm still sort of getting my feet wet with React Router, which is part of the problem.

Comment: What does the URL bar read when you click the link to the `newuser` route?

Comment: @JohnRogerson still not enough details, as you don't show anywhere at all where that `NewUser` component is mounted as a route in your first code snippet. where's the rest of the code? \

Comment: @MikeAbeln it shows the correct route  /newuser

Comment: @r3wt its there in the login form component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you shouldn't do conditional rendering, because when the user is not logged the Loggin component is rendered and is not depended on the path at all. then you change the path by clicking  Link to="/newuser" and the Sign up renders inside

Comment: try removing the conditional rendering , group all routes including newuser route and wrap them with the Switch component that is exported from react-router-dom.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation. i did exactly what you said, and it seems to be working fine now.  I'm going to post my code.  Probably a better way to do what I'm doing with the Redirects but this is a good start i think.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this working based on det2dachoppa's recommendations.  Removed the conditional and added the Switch and redirects to ensure that a user can't view the pages without logging in.

```
 <Router>
    <Notification />
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        {props.loggedUser && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Blogs />
            </Route>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {props.loggedUser && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/blogs">
              <Blogs />
            </Route>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {props.loggedUser && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/blogs/:id"
              render={({ match }) => (
                <Blog
                  blog={blogById(match.params.id)}
                  user={props.loggedUser}
                  history={props.history}
                />
              )}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}

        {props.loggedUser && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/users">
              <Users />
            </Route>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {props.loggedUser && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/users:id "
              render={({ match }) => (
                <User user={userById(match.params.id)} />
              )}
            />
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        {props.loggedUser && (
          <React.Fragment>
            <Route exact path="/newblog">
              <NewBlog />
            </Route>
          </React.Fragment>
        )}
        <Route path="/login">
          <Login />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/newuser">
          <NewUser />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/login">
          <Login />
        </Redirect>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

Comment: a better way to do this is to conditionally render the routes inside Switch like this: {props.loggedUser  && <Route exact path="/">} , repeat for every Route component you dont want to render if user is not logged and after the last route add just a single Redirect. Route queuing  matters because Switch renders the first route that points to the current path, but if the user is not logged, the condition protects those routes and Switch will reach the Redirect.

Comment: thanks for following up on this.  I did take your suggestions, and re-posted code above and all seems to be working.  Hopefully that's what you meant!

Comment: it is what i meant!  Just an other tweak for your code, you can wrap all the routes that are depended on the loggedUser  with a Fragment component exported from react and conditionally render it like this :  { props.loggedUser && <Fragment> your_protected_routes </Fragment>}.

Comment: hmm, okay i tried this (code re-edited) above, and now my /blogs and /users pages aren't showing any content, and my blogs/:id is redirecting to the login page.  see any issues?

Comment: i meant {props.loggedUser && <React.Fragment> -- put all the routes depended on loggedUser here -- </React.Fragment>. Additionally, for routes that you dont pass any props or match queries, you can render them like this : <Route exact path="/blogs" component={Blogs} />

Comment: Got it, thank you.  Any benefit to doing this, aside from cleaning up the code a bit?

Comment: i would say for readability, because you may add more routes in the future